# Definition and some examples of structure sheaves of affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was reading *algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves* written by Qing Liu and failed to understand some details about affine schemes.

**Notations:** Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit, $X = \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ its prime spectrum. For $f\in A$, let $$D(f) := \mathrm{Spec}(A) - V(f) = \{\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{Spec}(A):f\notin\mathfrak{p}\}.$$
To define the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ of $X$, one need only to define $$\mathcal{O}_X(D(f)) := A_f$$ for $f\in A$, where $A_f$ is the ring of fractions of $A$ w.r.t. $\{f^n: n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}\}$, then verify that these data defines a scheme.

Question 1.

> Let $D(f) \supset D(g)$, and take $b/f^k\in A_f$ s.t. its image in $A_{g}$ under the canonical homomorphism $A_f\to A_{g}$ is $0$. Then there is a $m > 0$ s.t. $bg^m = 0$ in $A$.

I don't know why such $m$ exists.
What I have tried: As I know, for a multiplicative subset $S$ of $A$, an element
$$a/s = 0\in S^{-1}A \iff \exists t\in S\, \mathrm{s.t.}\, ta = 0.$$
In the above case, assume that $g^n = af$, then $A_f\to A_g$ is determined by $$ 1/f\mapsto a/g^{n}. $$ So $b/f^k\mapsto ba^k/g^{nk} = 0\in A_g$ implies that there is a $m > 0$ s.t. $bg^m\cdot a^k = 0$ in $A$.

Question 2.

> Let $A$ be integral domain with $K$ its quotient field, $\xi = (0)\in X$, $f\in A$.
> Then the inclusion $\mathcal{O}_X(D(f)) = A_f\subset K = \mathcal{O}_{X, \xi}$ is the canonical map $\mathcal{O}_X(D(f))\to \mathcal{O}_{X, \xi}$.

I can't see why the inclusion is the canonical map.

Question 3.

> Let $A = \mathbb{Z}[T]$. For a prime number $p\in \mathbb{Z}$, $(T, p)$ is a maximal ideal in $A$. Let $U$ be the complement of the closed point $(T,p)\in X$, then $\mathcal{O}_X(U) = \mathbb{Z}[T]$.

In Liu's book, it argues that:

> $$ U = D(p)\cup D(T)
> \implies \mathcal{O}_X(U)\subset \mathcal{O}_X(D(p))\cap\mathcal{O}_X(D(T)) = \mathbb{Z}[T] \\ 
> \implies \mathcal{O}_X(U) = \mathbb{Z}[T].$$

But sadly none of the "$\implies$" is obvious to me :(

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: For Question 1, you are close, simply multiply your final equation by $f^k$.

Comment: For Question 2 and 3, note the fact that for an integral domain, all the localizations lie in the biggest localization, namely the fraction field. Use question 1, every localization map is inclusion, since the kernel is zero in this case.

Comment: @userunknown thank you! all of my questions have been solved and seem to be silly now :)